# If exist ID in array foreach, for every key = "id" PHP

Tags: php, arrays, find

EDIT:

I'm trying to use the method of Alex, but I have some problem...so I get the first array as $resultsAchievementsMe, like this:

```
$requestAchievementsMe = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/achievements?fields=data&app_id_filter=7606995873455'))->execute()->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());

$resultsAchievementsMe = $requestAchievementsMe ->asArray();
$tests = $resultsAchievementsMe['data'];

print_r($tests);
```

the print_r, will write this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [importance] => 0 [achievement] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6467916820996 [url] => https://www.***.com/test2.html [type] => game.achievement [title] => TITLE2!! ) ) [id] => 10206139019499208 ) )
```

this array, would contain more than 1 achievement, the user will unlock more than one...

now, with this:

```
     if (empty($resultsAchievementsMe)) {
        echo 'no achievements unlocked for now';
      }else {
        foreach ($resultsAchievementsMe['data'] as $tests) {
$totalAchievementsMe .= '[["' . $tests->data->achievement->id .'"],["'. $tests->data->achievement->title.'"]],';
     }  
    }
```

the output wuold be simple:

```
[["6467916820996"],["TEST2!!"]],
```

This array, would contain more information, I means, more achievement, because if the user unlock a new one, when he restart the app, this array will have another one with the same method (id),(name achievement).

Now, this another array, has all of the achievment, and I get with the similar method:

```
$requestAchievements = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/7606995873455/achievements'))->execute()->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());

$resultsAchievements = $requestAchievements ->asArray();

print_r($resultsAchievements);
```

the output of print_r, would be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://www.***.com/test2.html [type] => game.achievement [title] => TITLE2!! [image] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://www.***.com/test2.png [width] => 198 [height] => 198 ) ) [description] => description achievement2 [updated_time] => 2015-02-22T14:51:54+0000 [data] => stdClass Object ( [points] => 100 ) [id] => 6467916820996 [application] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7606995873455 [name] => myapp [url] => https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ ) [context] => stdClass Object ( [display_order] => 0 ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://www.***.com/test1.html [type] => game.achievement [title] => TEST1!! [image] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://www.***.com/test1.png [width] => 198 [height] => 198 ) ) [description] => description achievement1 [updated_time] => 2015-02-22T14:51:46+0000 [data] => stdClass Object ( [points] => 50 ) [id] => 7829964917383 [application] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7606995873455 [name] => EatSquare [url] => https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ ) [context] => stdClass Object ( [display_order] => 0 ) ) )
```

This array, has more information, like the description of the achievment, the url of the picture...etc... but with the similar method as before:

```
$expic = "png";
foreach ($resultsAchievements as $result) {

   $totalAchievements .= '[["' . $result->data->points .'"],["'. $UNLOCKED? .'"],["'. $result->title .'"],["'. $result->description .'"],["'. $result->id .'"],["'.  $result->url = substr($result->url, 0, -4).$expic.'"]],';
 }
```

I will get this:

```
[["100"],["TEST2!!"],["VARIABLE I NEED TO MAKE**"],["description achievement2"],["6467916820996"],["https://www.***.com/test2.png"]],[["50"],["TEST1!!"],["VARIABLE I NEED TO MAKE**"],["description achievement1"],["7829964917383"],["https://www.***.com/test1.png"]],
```

now, you can see, the user has the test2 id (6467916820996) unlocked from the first array... but I would like to make just one array, and insert a new value in the second one to see the all ID for each achievement unlocked...so, the final output will be like:

```
[["100"],["TEST2!!"],["UNLOCKED**"],["description achievement2"],["6467916820996"],["https://www.***.com/test2.png"]],[["50"],["TEST1!!"],["LOCKED!!!**"],["description achievement1"],["7829964917383"],["https://www.***.com/test1.png"]],
```

I try this method of Alex, but doesn't works...

```
$testid=$result->id;
    $exist=false;


    foreach($resultsAchievementsMe['data'] as $resultsAchievements){
       if($testid ==  $result->id) {  
          $totalAchievements .= $result->data->points .'"],["'. $result->title .'"],["'. 'UNLOCKED' .'"],["'. $result->description .'"],["'. $result->id .'"],["'.  $result->url .'"],';
          $exist=true;
          break;
      }
  }
  if ($exist == false) {
     $totalAchievements .=$result->data->points .'"],["'. $result->title .'"],["'. 'LOCKED!!!' .'"],["'. $result->description .'"],["'. $result->id .'"],["'.  $result->url.'"],["';
  }
```

someone has some idea? I can't use the example of Ghost because will change the characters of the output

thank you :)

Comment: the foreach is already okay, no need for that in_array, and why go manual with JSON string creation, just use json_encode

Comment: Does `$resultsAchievementsMe` always contain exactly one achievement? If not, what's the structure for two or more achievements?

Comment: no, the $resultsAchievementsMe can take more than one achievement, the problem is this, the user can unlock more achievement, and then, If I can make just one array from the two, to see what achievement was unlocked is perfect...I will try some test from the answer below... I will repost if everythings works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not 100% clear for me.

IMHO your code should be redesigned.

But if you need quick fix and you are sure that `$resultsAchievementsMe` include just 1 element than you can try this line:

```
$testid=$result->id;
if($testid == $resultsAchievementsMe['data'][0]['data']['achievement']['id'])) {
```

and if you have many in `$resultsAchievementsMe` you should use loop (or create some function):

```
    $testid=$result->id;
    $exist=false;
    foreach($resultsAchievementsMe['data'] as $myAchievement){
       if($testid ==  $myAchievement['data']['achievement']['id'])) {  
          $totalAchievements .= $result->data->points .'"],["'. $result->title .'"],["'. $result->description .'"],["'. $result->id .'"],["'.  $result->url'"],["'.'EXIST'.']';
          $exist=true;
          break;
      }
  }
  if ($exist == false) {
     $totalAchievements .=$result->data->points .'"],["'. $result->title .'"],["'. $result->description .'"],["'. $result->id .'"],["'.  $result->url'"],["'.'DOESN'T EXIST'.']';
  }
```

and by the way I don't understand if you really mix `array` with `json` you use `[]` and `{}` but in json if `{}` mean `object` - not array

anyway, I would prefer to get more detailed goal description, more complicated data source samples and and redesign this fragment to use json as json, array as array and objects as object.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I'm edit the original array with the "[]" because I have to open the string with another software... so, the output it's perfect like mine, I have to edit the original array